# How do you dynamically set ajax data in DataTables?

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm using DataTables 1.10.15 and have read about how you can specify the `data` attribute in an ajax call like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var MyTable = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "scripts/server_processing.php",
            "data": function ( d ) {
                d.myKey = "myValue";
                // d.custom = $('#myInput').val();
                // etc
            }
        }
    } );
} );
```

However, this example just has hardcoded values (or form input values like `$('#myInput').val()`).

I have an application where I need to be able to pass in various different objects of data and then have the ajax call run.

I can't see how this is possible and have looked at the following https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/custom_vars.html.

The reason I want to do this is because I'm building an application with **several different forms**. I need to choose **which form** to send as the data! When the users enter terms in a particular form, I want to pass *that* forms data to my ajax script and then have DataTables redraw the table (which I can do using the `.draw()` method):

```
MyTable.draw();
```

However, I don't understand how I can dynamically specify what goes in `data:`. I *could* do something like this in the ajax call:

```
"ajax": { 
        "url" : "scripts/server_processing.php",
        "data" : function ( d ) {
            d.primarySearch = $('#form1').serialize(),
            d.secondSearch = $('#form2').serialize(),
            d.thirdSearch = $('#form3').serialize(),
        }
    }
```

But, if the data I'm doing the search on is in `#form1`, I just want to pass that data, and not the data from `#form2` and `#form3`. But since that varies each time, I need to be able say which form(s) to pass in to the `data:` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also using the server side processing.
you can call it as per below code:

> This is for static form id

```
  ajax: {
            "url": 'api/v1/datatable/' + method,
            "type": "POST",
            "data": jQuery('#frmid').serialize(),
        },
```

> This is for dynamic form id

```
var form_id = 'form1' ;

$(document).ready(function() {
    var MyTable = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "scripts/server_processing.php",
            "data": jQuery('#' + form_id).serialize(),
        }
    } );
} );

$(document).on('keyup','.search_text',function(){

    form_id = $(this).closest('form').attr('id');
    MyTable.draw(); 
})
```

Hope this will helpful to  you.

Comment: Thanks that is helpful. I already understand that but the problem is what if you have several forms? What if one time you want to send all the fields from `#form1` and another time all the fields from `#form2` to the ajax script?

Comment: @Andy, is this helpful to you?

Comment: Yes, but how/where do you pass `form.id` *dynamically*? That's the whole problem. In DataTables you cannot initialise it more than once, so repeating the `$('#example').DataTable` part for different forms won't work. This is the problem I'm having - I can't pass anything in to the `.DataTable` initialisation in a way where things could be set dynamically. I'll update the code I have to show the issue more clearly.

Comment: @Andy, you are clicking any button for search the data?

Comment: No, it works on a `keyup` event. But if you can post something that works with a button I can probably adapt it.

Comment: then on click set that form id in one variable and pass that variable. like dynamic option

Comment: WHERE and HOW do you pass it? This is the whole problem. I can easily assign a form ID to a variable. How do I reference that inside the `DataTables` constructor? Hint: it's not a simple case of just putting `var form_id`!

Comment: @Andy, i made some changes as per your requirement, check it and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
ajax: {
                url: "{{ route('admin.deposits.index') }}",
                data: {
                    filter: $('#filter form').serialize(); // **not dynamic**
                }
            },
```

to

```
ajax: {
                url: "{{ route('admin.deposits.index') }}",
                data: {
                    filter: function () { // dynamic
                        return $('#filter form').serialize();
                    }
                }
            },
```

then you can use **table.ajax.reload()** with dynamic data.

This solved my problem.

Answer (score -3):

If you just need to change the datatable's ajax initial url later in your code, you can use:

```
tbl.ajax.url("new url");
```

[API Documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.url())

Comment: It's already been answered and this has literally nothing to do with the question.

Comment: `tbl.ajax.url("https://example.com?" + jQuery('#' + form_id).serialize());` Now it has!